# CSS block bottom border

Tags: html, css

I have a div that I would like to have a bottom border.

This can be see at http://jsfiddle.net/R5YN2/

What causes the border to not be placed right at the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your container element isn't accounting for the `float`ed elements and is basically collapsing.

Give it the property `overflow: auto` and it should work:

```
#recurring-header-wrapper {
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

    overflow: auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/R5YN2/14/

---

Also, go easy on the class names. You can have selectors that target classes inside of elements:

```
#recurring-header-wrapper .label
```

Which matches *only* `.label` elements inside of the `recurring-header-wrapper` element. No need for huge class names.

Answer (score 1):

If you float things you have to clear as well.

Read this: http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

This is what you're looking for. Add the class .clearfix to your wrapper-div (#recurring-header-wrapper).

```
.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: like this : http://jsfiddle.net/R5YN2/12/ . Notice `<div style="clear:both"></div>`line, on HTML codes.

Comment: While this solves the problem I personally think you should clear without having to add any extra markup. But that's more a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

It is displayed at the bottom (it ends there, the text is overflowing. Check that with `overflow:hidden` and most of the text disappear). Add a height to the div to make it the size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: the `float:left`.

To correct that you can add `overflow: auto` to `#recurring-header-wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

the floated divs inside cause this. you can clear them.
http://jsfiddle.net/R5YN2/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here's the quick fix. Basically when you float left the header groups get taken out of the flow unless you clear them with something (an empty div is fine)

```
<div id="recurring-header-wrapper">
    <div class="recurring-header-group">
        <div class="recurring-header-label">Label</div>
        <div class="recurring-header-item">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="recurring-header-group">
        <div class="recurring-header-label">Label</div>
        <div class="recurring-header-item">Item</div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `overflow: hidden` on your recurring header wrapper http://jsfiddle.net/R5YN2/16/